# How to replace a parameter in all of my url's using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

how do i replace a parameter in all of my url's using .htaccess ?

for example, in this url

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=section&id=14&Itemid=117

i would like to change "section" to "category", like this:

http://www.mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=14&Itemid=117

i tried this, but it won't do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=section([^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?view=category%1 [R,L]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)view=section(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1view=category%2 [R,L]
```

This rule replaces the word section by category without affecting any other URL argument.

Comment: Sure, I tested it in my apache2 server before posting... ;).